# How to insert a .html template file contents in a sql server project script ?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, relational-database

I have a html template whom I want to insert in a SQL Script @variable, so that I could use it to insert in the database.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Couldn't find any thing for trying. But the most general way is to type the html in the .sql file, which is currently followed in the project. But, this seems to be really bad when understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Insert it to a table or assign it to a variable

```
DECLARE @MyCode NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  
    @MyCode = '<HTML>
        <BODY>
            My Sampel HTML Code
        </BODY>
    </HTML>'

INSERT INTO MyCodetable
(
    HTMLCode
)
VALUES(@MyCode)
```

Comment: I want to seprate the .html file and .sql file. Don't want to mix it.